# FullCalendar not working with Google Calendar SEC7120

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cors, fullcalendar

I'm trying to integrate Google Calendar with FullCalendar. I followed steps in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar and filled in my information.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                aspectRatio: 4,
                plugins: [ 'timeGrid' ,'googleCalendar', 'list'],
                defaultView: 'listWeek',
                googleCalendarApiKey: 'A...g',
                eventSources:[                        
                    {
                        googleCalendarId: 'l...@gmail.com'//primary calendar
                    },
                    {
                        googleCalendarId: '7...nk@group.calendar.google.com',//second calendar
                    }],
                header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: ''
                },
            });
            calendar.render();
        });
```

However, there is no event shown and the console says

> SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'file://' did not find 'file://' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/7jmaq...lts=9999'.

Clicking the link provided gives below result:

> {
>    "kind": "calendar#events", "etag": "\"...qe80g\"", "summary": "...", "updated": "2019-09-28T21:29:49.573Z", "timeZone": "...", "accessRole": "reader", "defaultReminders": [], "nextSyncToken": "CIiX05...YAQ==", "items": [  {   "kind": "calendar#event",   "etag": "\"31....9146000\"",
>      "id": "2do9...h04",   "status": "confirmed",   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MmR...tAZw",   "created": "2019-09-28T21:29:49.000Z",   "updated": "2019-09-28T21:29:49.573Z",   "summary": "Test",   "creator": {    "email": "l...@gmail.com"   },   "organizer": {    "email": "7...mnk@group.calendar.google.com",    "displayName": "...",    "self": true   },   "start": {    "dateTime": "2019-09-28T17:00:00-04:00"   },   "end": {    "dateTime": "2019-09-28T18:00:00-04:00"   },   "iCalUID": "2...04@google.com",   "sequence": 0  } ]}

All in all, the calendar works fine but it can't obtain any events information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key issue here is this part of the error message:

> The origin 'file://'

You need to serve your page over `http://` or `https://` before it can work.

Browser security restrictions prevent files loaded locally (as opposed to a webserver - even if that webserver runs on the same machine) using the `file://` protocol from making Ajax requests to remote sites. This makes certain kinds of phishing attacks more difficult.

Install a free webserver on your machine and serve your page that way.